# DisplayNameFor doesn't lookup resx file despite IStringLocalizer and IHtmlLocalizer working correctly in the Razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-localization

I've got my `Login.cshtml` page

```
@page
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<LoginModel> localizer
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<LoginModel> htmlLocalizer
@model LoginModel

<h1>@htmlLocalizer["Title"]</h1> TRANSLATES WELL
<h1>@localizer["Title"]</h1> TRANSLATES WELL
[...]
div class="checkbox">
   <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe" class="form-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe) //DOESN'T WORK, DOESN'T LOOKUP RESX FILE
    </label>
</div>
```

In the scaffolded `Login.cshtml.cs` page model there is an attribute [Display] fr the RememberMe property, but this one is not getting translated despite translation being put in the same resource file

```
        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = "Remember")] //DOESN'T WORK, DOESN'T LOOKUP RESX FILE
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
```

We can see that the structure is correct

[image]

Resx file itself:

[image]

This is what gets rendered:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add [data annotations localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0#dataannotations-localization) in startup:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
            options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Microsoft's bug which I reported: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Custom-tool-cant-generate-designer-file/10213747?

> Steps to reproduce:
>
> Create ASP.Net Core MVC app Create resources directory Create resource
> file called name.pl.resx Add few keypairs Build Expected behaviour:
> Designer file is generate the resx file can be referenced as a type in
> the code.
>
> Actual behaviour: Error: Custom tool PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
> failed to produce an output for input file…
>
> Workaround: With each resx file edition
>
> remove locale from its name Unload projectt Releoad project Clean
> Build Rename resx file to contain locale again